# Sections aren't continuous

Tags: css

I'm a newbie in HTML and on [my page](http://d.websupport.sk/janeviemus.tk/index.html#privitanie), I have the problem that my two sections aren't continuous:

```css
.privitanie{
position: absolute;
background: url("../images/pozadie.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
z-index: 0;
}

.uvod{
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="privitanie" id="privitanie">...</section>

<section class="uvod" id="uvod">...</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely-positioned elements are outside the document flow. Other elements end up layered above or below, depending on their position in the markup. Make both relative, or give `.uvod` a top margin equal to the height of `.privitanie`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy solution that does not require changing too much of your code:

```
.uvod{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Change margin-top to whatever you prefer.

Comment: margin-top: 50% mess with menu but padding-top: 50% work well thanks